# Import lib with multiple flavor

Tags: android, gradle, aar, android-flavors

I have a lib with this flavors:

```
        flavorDimensions "dim"
    productFlavors {
        nocustomer {
            versionNameSuffix "-nocustomer"
            dimension = "dim"
        }
        customer001 {
            versionNameSuffix "-customer001"
            dimension = "dim"
        }
    }
```

My build produce this file:

[image]

How to use my library with different flavors?
Example: i want to build an app that use nocustomer flavor. What should i write on gradle app file? Which library to include?